# Providing a mock to another mocks constructor?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking, phpunit, tdd

I'm curious about whether I'm doing things right here, as I'm new to testing.

I have two services (so far), `AuthService` and `CommentService`. `CommentService` depends on `AuthService`, and `AuthService` depends on a 3rd party class (`\SlimSession\Helper`).

In my unit test for `AuthService` I simply mock `\SlimSession\Helper` and provide the mock to the constructor.

Now, in my test for `CommentService` I mock the `AuthService` and provide it to the constructor of the `CommentService`. But I must also create a mock of the `\SlimSession\Helper` again to provide it to the constructor of my mocked `AuthService`.

```
$session = $this->getMockBuilder('\SlimSession\Helper')
  ->getMock();

$auth = $this->getMockBuilder('\App\Service\AuthService')
  ->setConstructorArgs([$session])
  ->getMock();

$auth->expects($this->any())->method('isLoggedIn')->willReturn(false);
$auth->expects($this->any())->method('getLoggedInUserId')->willReturn(0);
```

Is this right? It seems a bit silly to have to provide a (mock) dependency to a mock object, since it won't use that dependency anyway.

My question regards `PHPUnit` in particular, but I guess it could be made generally for unit testing.

Comment: is there a reason for you can't use `->disableOriginalConstructor()` when creating a mock for Auth?

Comment: @xmike Ah! I had missed that option, thanks! Now it makes more sense :D

Comment: Guess it would make sense to turn that comment into an answer then ...